# How are thoughts biologicaly generated?

Tags: neuroscience, brain, neurology, neuron

I want to know how thoughts are biologicaly generated. I know that electrical impulses can trigger formed memories in the brain but what I want to know is how the electrical impulse is generated in the first place. I don't have a background in biology or neurology but I think it's probably one of the three options:

1. Impulses are generated randomly at parts where there are stronger connections.
2. We have loops in our neural network, electrical impulses stay and go around the brain to trigger memories and thoughts.
3. We are deterministic and only react to impulses from the outside.

Any reading suggestions about this topic are also highly appreciated. I want to understand the human brain a little more to compare it to artifical neural networks.

Comment: Hi! It's an interesting question, though I would caution you to narrow down your question, it's very broad. I also warn you to not confuse thoughts or memories with neur(ologic)al activity, this will run you into the [hard problem of consciousness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_problem_of_consciousness). Please also show some effort in trying to answer your own question; for instance, what exactly is it that you don't understand? You will have to show some independent effort for your question not to be closed or marked as a homework question.

Comment: An addendum: since neural circuitry is *extremely* varied, you will find many examples of all sorts of circuits, including those you list. For instance, there exist neurons with a pace-making activity that generate their own activity from within, as well as neurons that only respond to outside stimuli, such as many kinds of sensory neurons. And everything in between... including neurological dysfunctions. You MUST narrow your question and also be very cautious about comparing all of that to artificial neural networks (the analogy is full of common pitfalls and frequent misunderstandings).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Although not posted as an answer your response did help me out. Do you have a resource suggestion where I can deepen my knowledge about different neural activities and differences? I know that artifical neural networks in the current state are completly different from how our brains work. I do believe though that a lot can be learned from our human brains for AI. I think my question can be closed now. And sorry again for the form of my question.

Comment: Please take a look [here](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/7880/what-is-the-difference-between-biological-and-artificial-neural-networks) and try searching *"how are biological and artificial neural networks different"* in a search engine. There are many duplicate answers on psychology.SE and biology.SE and so many more answers and posts about it elsewhere. Good luck!